# Shared DbContext among .NET Core and Full .NET

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

we have quite a big database that we have a shared code-first model (we don't use migrations). This model is packed into NuGet package and exposed to internal NuGet feed.
This NuGet is consumed by several solutions that together contain many apps (some big web apps, a lot of smaller tools).

For example, there are solutions for these:

- the main website (e-shop)
- administration
- API
- B2B portal
- several synchronizers (populating products catalog from several suppliers)
- reporting tools
- transactions analyzers
- other supportive tools

All of these apps are written in the full .NET 4.7 referencing the same internal NuGet package with DbContext.
We would love to refactor some apps to use .NET Core 2.

We are looking for a way to create DbContexts NuGet with as much shared code as possible. 
For example, create the POCO classes in a project targeting .NET Standard and then create two projects for DbContext - One targeting .NET framework and one targeting .NET Core? We need to avoid making every change twice whenever some database change happens.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to do this, you will need to remove every reference to Entity Framework 6 and replace them with Entity Framework Core, as it's the only version that runs on both .NET Framework and .NET Core.

Comment: I that really sensible? For each database change you have to test the *whole* application suite while it's likely that only a few of them are actually affected. I think I'd prefer specialized contexts for each application (or groups of them) so one database modification may only touch a couple of them or even just one. Maybe some of these smaller tools only need a very limited subset of tables that may be stable for years.

Comment: Gert Arnold That is true, however different tools require different tables. That would mean to duplicate a lot of POCO classes, which would be the situation we are trying to avoid.